# Не подключается к vps с моего рабочего ip адреса

Tags: ip, access, vps

Есть белый статический ip адрес на рабочем компьютере с вин 10. И есть vps(или vds как у них на сайте написано) на ihor.ru.
На нем ubuntu 20.04. После установки подключился и настроил доступ по ssh ключу.

Затем через некоторое время, я попытался зайти на сервер по ssh ключу. И не смог. Ошибка , сервер отклонил ключи или что то такое. Я зашел через vnc, включил доступ оп паролю. Все равно пишет доступ запрещен.
Я переустановил ubuntu на сервере, пытаюсь подключиться - доступ запрещен.

Установил терминал на телефон и с мобильной сети смог зайти.
Установил vpn на рабочий комп и тоже смог зайти под другим ip.

На сервере открыл логи в /var/log/auth.log. Моего ip там просто нет. Есть куча других в том числе тот с которого я через vpn подключался. Но моего реального ip там не появляется.
Спросил у тех поддержки сервера, сказали ничего не блокируется.
Запусти winMTR пакеты отправляются и доходят потерь нет.

В итоге подключается со всех ip кроме моего рабочего.
Что не так, как подключится?

Comment: А кто именно пишет про доступ запрещен и какой конкретно текст? А если включить подробный вывод логов (`ssh -v` или `ssh -vv` или `ssh -vvv` или типа того) там будет что-нибудь интересное?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Admin_PC> ssh -v root@139.xxx.xxx.xxx

Кучу текста про то что ключь не найден или не соответствует. Далее вход по паролю

debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
root@139.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
Permission denied, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

смотри, у тебя пишет `can't open /dev/tty` на сайте [убунту](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2248801) вот такое решение (если в кратце) `sudo -u username ssh -i 139.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416166/cant-establish-ssh-connection-debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-n вообще ещё глянь вот по этой ссылочке ответ, может вычтешь, что по твоей проблеме. https://serverfault.com/questions/251876/debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address-when-t и вот ещё есть, тоже можешь прочитать

Comment: Я подключаюсь из виндовс 10. Удалив папку .ssh в папке пользователя. Так же пробую через pytty. Эти ответы актуальны для ubuntu. По-прежнему не понимаю в чем причина. На самом сервере точно нет проблем, т.к. там стоит чистая ubuntu с доступом по паролю. Послу удаления .ssh при подключении идет запрос генерации нового ключа. Я ввожу yes и потом вновь доступ запрещен.